# TF400813: The user {userguid}is not authorized to access this resource

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am getting below error when reading licensing information of user in VSTS.

> TF400813: The user 'userguid' is not authorized to access this
>   resource.

```
VssOAuthAccessTokenCredential accessTokenCredentials = new VssOAuthAccessTokenCredential(new VssOAuthAccessToken(accessToken));
                var credentials = new VssClientCredentials(accessTokenCredentials);
                credentials.Storage = new VssClientCredentialStorage();

                VssConnection connection = new VssConnection(new Uri(this.ServerUri), credentials);
                var licensingHttpClient = connection.GetClient<LicensingHttpClient>();
                var accountEntitlement = licensingHttpClient.GetAccountEntitlementAsync().Result;
                var license = accountEntitlement.License;
```

Comment: What is your question? The error message seems pretty clear.

Comment: So it is not allowed for a user to read license information having credentials with oAuth Token?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly make sure you have the correct permission to read the licensing information.

The issue is mainly caused by the VSTS account is not connect with the AAD which your user account is stored in.

If the email address is not a Microsoft email, it will be backed to AAD when connecting the VSTS account. If the client VSTS is not connected this AAD or connected with another AAD, you will not be authorized to login the client VSTS account.

Just try below things to narrow down the issue:

- **Connect VSTS to Azure AAD**

  Detail information about connect VSTS account to AAD, you can refer
  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/accounts/connect-account-to-aad).
- **Use Microsoft email login your client VSTS account.**

  You can use a Microsoft email address (such as user@outlook.com or
  user@hotmail.com etc). Just add the Microsoft email to the VSTS
  account.

Comment: I can get all projects of collection with credentials created with oAuth token but unable to get Licence information of user.

Comment: @arsalanyounus Yeah,actually it's an permission issue. Just check your oAuth token , make sure you have granted the `vso.entitlements` and `vso.memberentitlementmanagement` scopes for your oAuth token.